# 12V,20W bulb connection doubt

Tags: transformer, parallel

I have 8 12V,20W bulbs and want to connect them in series. I cant seem to find a 12V,160W transformer for my 240V mains supply.
Is there another way like connecting in series+parallel connection to use them directly with 240V mains?
Any suggestion is welcome...

Comment: You wouldn't connect your 8 bulbs to a 12V, 160 Watt transformer in series.  You would connect them in parallel.  Also, a quick google turns up 240V to 12V 160Watt transformers available literally all over the place.

Comment: Add another 12 bulbs in series. 20x12 = 240V - this is how Christmas tree lights used to be wired in the old days - though they weren't 20W bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

12V bulbs and the lamps in which you use them are in general NOT designed to be run directly off the mains voltage. They are designed to run with a transformer which provides mains isolation.

I would advise you to get not one but several transformers like 2 times 80 W or 4 transformers of 40 W.

Also 20W bulbs are very oldfashioned, why not get some LED lights instead, for the same amount of light you would only need one 30 W transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Eight 12 volt lamps in series will result in the highest possible resistance, and will require only 96 volts to drive them to 20 watts each so, without finding some way to drop the extra 144 volts, you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The 12v lamps are ELV which means that they are NOT safe for mains voltages.

Are the fittings double insulated? I bet you they are not.

I don't want you to fry anyone.

DON'T DO THIS!